# tkinter window doesn't display - if .event time is 0 inside loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I was racking my brain a bit trying to figure out why a tkinter window would only appear after I had stopped my script.  Turns out, it won't appear if the delay time in my root.after (that is within my infinite fruity loop) was set to 0.  Setting it to 1 or higher caused it to work correctly.  Is this a bug or am I missing something important about how .after works?  I'm running this with Python 2.7 in Anaconda on mac OS.

```
import time
import Tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random numbers")    
root.geometry("220x220+5+5")

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=210, height=210)
frame.pack()

luckynumber = tk.IntVar()

label1 = tk.Label(frame, text="random number").pack(side=tk.LEFT)

display1 = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=luckynumber)
display1.pack( side=tk.LEFT )

def askrandy():
    randy = random.randrange(0, 100, 1)
    luckynumber.set(randy)

def fruityloop():

    time.sleep(.5)
    askrandy()
    root.after(1, fruityloop)

root.after(0, fruityloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Second question: this code doesn't run very smoothly.  Seeing as it's quite simple, I assumed it would be pretty solid.  But I find that it takes a couple seconds to get started and moving the window around causes it to stutter as well.  Would this work better with my main loop run as a class?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You're not supposed to use `time.sleep` in a GUI.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch,  Q1 = Is this a bug or am I dumb?  Q2 = Should this code run smoothly?

Comment: @chmedly 
I have tried it and I have not had any problems.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 True, got a lot method, `after`, `Thread`, etc...

Comment: you can use `root.after(500, fruitloop)` instead of `sleep.time(.5)` - it will repeat `fruitloop` after 500ms = 0.5s

Comment: you can put all your functions before `tk.Tk()` to make code more readable.

Comment: do you run it in `IDLE` ? try directly in console `python script.py`

Comment: @ everyone, Thanks for the input!  What I posted is a simplification of the code I'm working on. My real code includes some serial port stuff and the pyserial example code from which I stole used a few sleeps so I tried to wrap up all of those into one sleep for this example. I have since tried removing all the sleeps and put all the delay into the .after and it works splendidly!  I'm slightly less dumb now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior.

Tkinter maintains a queue of work to be done when it goes idle. This is the "idle" queue.

When you call `after`, the function you supply is added to this queue. When the main event loop (or a call to `after_idle`) processes the queue, it looks for items on the queue that should be run based on the current time and the time that the item should be run. All items that are due to be run are run before processing of the queue stops.

If one of those adds an item to the queue with a value of zero it will be run since its time is due. If that item itself adds an item to the queue, then you take one item off of the queue and immediately put one one so the queue will never become empty. If the queue never becomes empty, tkinter isn't able to process other types of events.

The reason that the program seems slow and jerky is because of the call to `sleep`. When you call `sleep`, tkinter does exactly that: it sleeps. It cannot process any events, even events that simply refresh the window. If you want `askrandy` to be called once every half second, you should simply call `after` with a value of 500, rather than call it with a value of zero and then sleep for half a second.

Whether the main window is a class or not will not affect your program all all. You simply need to stop using `sleep`, and provide sane values to `after`. If you are trying to show a simple animation, a value of 30 is about as small as you need to go.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it should looks without `sleep()`. But I don't know if it can help. It works fast on Linux.

If you run code in `IDLE` then you may have problem because it uses `Tkinter` to display windows and runs own `mainloop()` but `Tkinter` should run only one `mainloop()`. You can try directly in console `python script.py`.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def fruityloop():
    randy = random.randrange(0, 100, 1)
    luckynumber.set(randy)

    # run again after 500ms = 0.5s
    root.after(500, fruityloop)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("random numbers")    
root.geometry("220x220+5+5")

luckynumber = tk.IntVar()

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=210, height=210)
frame.pack()

label = tk.Label(frame, text="random number")
label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

display = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=luckynumber)
display.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# run first time
fruityloop()

root.mainloop()
```